applescript excel saving sheet from workbook as PDF
i have the following applescript code to save the range of a excel sheet as a PDF document:
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    
    set pdfMaker to POSIX file "/Users/me/Documents/client files/testing.xlsx" -- specify the path to your Excel file
    open pdfMaker
    delay 1
    activate
    
    tell worksheet 1 of active workbook
        set theRange to range "B2:H15" -- specify the range you want to save as PDF
        set filePath to "Users:me:Documents:client files:reciepts:test.pdf" -- specify the path to save the PDF
        select theRange
        
        -- Save as PDF
        save as active sheet filename filePath file format PDF file format
        
    end tell
end tell

im getting this error for the save as line of code
error "Microsoft Excel got an error: Parameter error." number -50
Ive tried searching through google and using chatGPT but neither worked.
EDIT(new code):
set workbookName to "testing.xlsx"
set clientFiles to (path to documents folder as text) & "client files:"
set workbookPath to clientFiles & workbookName

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    
    set theSheet to sheet "test sheet" of workbook workbookName
    
    set pdfName to "testing"
    set pdfPath to clientFiles & "reciepts:" & pdffName & ".pdf"
    
    save as theSheet filename pdfPath file format PDF file format
    
end tell


Try moving the save as… line outside of the tell worksheet 1… line. As is, you are doing something like this… active sheet of worksheet 1 of workbook…, which is incorrect. Also, you cannot save a range, only a sheet. If you wish for only a range to be saved as a pdf, you must put the contents of that range into its own sheet. For example: create a new sheet, put those values in it, save the sheet, delete the sheet. You might do a search as well as there is at least one answer for saving a worksheet as a pdf using applescript.

This question is similar to: How to convert excel sheet to pdf automatically using applescript?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

thanks for that information on the ranges. i took a look at that other post, and it seems to be what i want. ive figured out how to save it as a pdf, but instead of only saving one of the sheets, it keeps saving all the sheets in the workbook. ive edited the original post with my new code.

I'm glad that you've worked it out. It's kind of awkward but one solution for the sheets is to copy the active sheet to a new document, where it will be the only sheet. This is scriptable as well. Or you could delete every sheet except the one you desire, print, then close without saving. It's kind of strange though as the dictionary suggests that you must specify the sheet to print.
